# Como faço para contar quantas listas duplicadas existem em um array numpy python?

Tags: python, numpy

Olá pessoal tudo bem? Sou novo nos estudo de aprendizado de máquina e venho aqui pedir uma auxilio de como posso proceder para contar quantas sub listas possuem o mesmo valor em um array no numpy python conforme o exemplo abaixo:

Tamanho todas do array é 395 sub listas.

```
array_1 = [[0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0]]
array_2 = [[0,0,2,2,,[0,0,0,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2],[0,2,0,2,0],[0,0,2,2,2],[0,0,0,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2],[0,2,0,2,0]]
```

como tenho que exibir:

> coluna_2    countagem
>
> 0,0,1,1,1      2
>
> 1,1,1,1,1      2
>
> 0,2,0,2,0      2
>
> 0,2,0,2,0      2

Tentei utilizar esse código porem não deu certo.

```
h = pd.DataFrame(array_1, columns=[0,1,2,3,4])
duplicateRowsDF = h.pivot_table(index=[0,1,2,3,4], aggfunc='size')
print(duplicateRowsDF)
```

Gostaria de um auxilio dos colegas pois não consigo achar uma ideia clara.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, talvez pode ser mais simples,

```
import collections

array = [[0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],
           [1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0],
           [0,0,1,1,1],[0,0,0,1,1],
           [1,1,1,1,1],[0,1,0,1,0]]

contador = collections.Counter(array)
for i in range(len(array)): 
    print('%s: %d'% (array[i],c[tuple(array[i])]))
```

terá como saída

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]: 2
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]: 2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]: 2
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]: 2
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1]: 2
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1]: 2
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]: 2
[0, 1, 0, 1, 0]: 2
```